# Is it possible to expand the height of a div with no contents?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure why I can't seem to figure this out today?   Normally floating a column to the left or right is no problem.  This particular case I suppose is unique because I don't actually have anything in the left column.

The issue is laid out in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj2RK/).

The issue is I need the content in the right column to vertically stretch the left column. The only time I can achieve this result is by manually giving the left column a height.  Thanks for any help.

**HTML**

```
<div style="width: 940px;">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right">
    Main content blah blah blah
</div>
<div class="clr"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.right {
    float:left;
    background-color: red;
}

.clr {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use floating or want old browser support (IE7), you can use

```
.wrapper {
    width: 940px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.left, .right {
    padding-bottom: 1000000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000000px;
    min-height: 1px;
}
```

Where `1000000px` can be any big value greater than the height of the columns.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rj2RK/2/)

Comment: I'll accept this answer.  thank you.  it's a real bad situation in my opinion the design in question I'm trying to get reconsidered so I can avoid these types of styles.  It's a very informative answer though, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend removing floating and using

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
}
.left, .right {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rj2RK/3/)